# What is the best way to vectorize a iterative function in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, data-science

I'm working with a function that quotes the value of a given person portfolio. To work with this function, I need to iterate over the rows of the dataframe and apply this function:

```
x$cota <- 100

cotiza <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if (i > 1){
      x[i,]$cota <- ((x[i,]$pl - x[i,]$mov)/x[i-1,]$pl) * x[i-1,]$cota
    }
  return (x)
}
```

This is the dataframe which the function is applied to:

```
    data    pl     mov cota
1 2018-01-01 500.0  250000  100
2 2018-01-02 525.0       0  100
3 2018-01-03 997.2 -100000  100
4 2018-01-04 500.0       0  100
5 2018-01-05 520.0       0  100
```

The output of the function on this dataframe should look like:

```
    data    pl     mov     cota
1 2018-01-01 500.0  250000   100.00
2 2018-01-02 525.0       0   105.00
3 2018-01-03 997.2 -100000 20199.44
4 2018-01-04 500.0       0 10128.08
5 2018-01-05 520.0       0 10533.20
```

Is there anyway to make this function vectorizable so I can apply it to the dataframe?

Comment: Since you are referencing a previous row when assigning the current row, this becomes a "rolling function", meaning there is likely no way to vectorize it. In general, if you cannot calculate one value in isolation from its neighbors, it's not easy (or at times possible) to truly vectorize it. Is there something wrong with using your function as-is?

Comment: BTW: (1) looks like an incomplete copy/paste, there is at least a closing `}` missing from `cotiza`, is anything else missing? (2) You can replace `for (i in 1:nrow(x)) { if (i > 0) { ... } }` with `for (i in seq_len(nrow(x))[-1]) { ... }` (no `if`), good for two reasons: no `if`, and if you get an empty frame, then `1:nrow(x)` evals to `1:0` which does *not* result in "no rows processed", and `seq_len(nrow(x))[-1]` will never evaluate if 0 or 1 rows are present.

Comment: No @r2evans, there is nothing wrong to use as it is! Actually, it's working just fine. A friend of mine suggested to vectorize all functions so I was able to work with it in the R style. Since there is no other way to do that easily so, I'll stick with it.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the optimization suggestion! Gonna try that!

Comment: I'm a huge fan of vectorizing when it makes sense. I think since `cota[3]` which relies on `cota[2]` which relies on `cota[1]`, there is very little to be done. That is, unless you can change the math that goes into it. (If it were just one variable you lag, then you could likely work around it, but in this case lagging both `pl` and `cota`, the polynomial expansion does not facilitate workarounds.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the comment! Could you please answer the question so I can close it?

Comment: There are 3 open { but only 2 close }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `cota[3]` relies on the updated value of `cota[2]` which relies on `cota[1]`, you cannot do simple vectorization of this function. Sometimes you can cheat by using `cumsum`, `cumprod`, or similar cumulative functions (that are still iterative but in really optimized code), but it relies on "simple iterative accumulation". In this case, however, a sequence of

```
cota[2] = cota[1] * (pl[2] - mov[2]) / pl[1],
cota[3] = cota[2] * (pl[3] - mov[3]) / pl[2]
```

if you replace `cota[2]`, you get

```
(cota[1] * (pl[2] - mov[2]) / pl[1]) * (pl[3] - mov[3]) / pl[2]
```

which is effectively

```
cota[1] * (pl[2]*pl[3] - pl[2]*mov[3] - pl[3]*mov[2] + mov[2]*mov[3]) / (pl[1] * pl[2])
```

which does not immediately lend itself to simple cumulative operators.

Some functions providing rolling-windows of sorts, specifically `zoo::rollapply`, but often they are doing a `for` loop under the hood. (Technically, I believe most `*apply` functions are also doing `for` loops under the hood, though likely *well* under the hood.)

If you have performance issues with this or similar functions, you can always use `Rcpp` or similar speed-ups. (Once you get into `Rcpp`-territory, you might find that a raw `for` loop will beat vectorized code, even `Rcpp`-native vectorization, though that depends a lot on many other things.)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end try using `cumprod` like this:

```
cotiza2 <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  if (n < 2) return(x)
  transform(x, cota = cumprod(c(cota[1], (pl - mov)[-1] / pl[-n])))
}

cotiza2(x)
##         data    pl     mov     cota
## 1 2018-01-01 500.0  250000   100.00
## 2 2018-01-02 525.0       0   105.00
## 3 2018-01-03 997.2 -100000 20199.44
## 4 2018-01-04 500.0       0 10128.08
## 5 2018-01-05 520.0       0 10533.20
```

**2)** This isn't vectorized but it is shorter than the code in the question and less tricky than (1).

```
cotiza3 <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  if (n < 2) return(x)
  within(x, for(i in 2:n) cota[i] <- (pl[i] - mov[i]) / pl[i-1] * cota[i-1])
}

cotiza3(x)
##         data    pl     mov     cota
## 1 2018-01-01 500.0  250000   100.00
## 2 2018-01-02 525.0       0   105.00
## 3 2018-01-03 997.2 -100000 20199.44
## 4 2018-01-04 500.0       0 10128.08
## 5 2018-01-05 520.0       0 10533.20
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
    data    pl     mov cota
1 2018-01-01 500.0  250000  100
2 2018-01-02 525.0       0  100
3 2018-01-03 997.2 -100000  100
4 2018-01-04 500.0       0  100
5 2018-01-05 520.0       0  100"
x <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

### Update

Added (1).

Comment: I was trying to find a use for `cumprod` there, could not get it right. Nice work.